# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol khpu referenced in function "private: void __cdecl

Tags: c++, kdb

I added c.obj from https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/tree/master/w64 - #pragma comment(lib, "c.obj")

But I am getting this error

```
\3rdParty\kdb\c.obj : warning LNK4003: invalid library format; library ignored

5>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol k referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl...

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ktd referenced in function "private: void __cdecl ...

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol khpu referenced in function "private: void __cdecl ...

fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I have tried everything there in google but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) it is said that :

```
#pragma comment( lib, "commenstring" )
```

> **lib**
>
> Places a library-search record in the object file. This comment type must be accompanied by a *commentstring* parameter **containing the name (and possibly the path) of the library** that you want the linker to search.

It searches for a library not an object file.

You should have a `.lib` file to include with this `pragma` directive.

It should be something like :

```
#pragma comment( lib, "c.lib" )
```

Comment: I tried c.lib, then I get an error -> c.dll not found even though it is in the same folder as c.lib

Comment: @user2256532 You get this error at the execution I suppose. Put c.dll inside your binary folder.

Comment: yes.. error is during execution.. where is binary folder?

Comment: @user2256532 You should have a `bin/Release` or `bin/Debug` in your project directory. If you are compiling in debug for example, just copy the `c.dll` inside `your_project_folder\bin\Debug`

Comment: Yeah this worked.. Thanks
Is there any way to reference to some other folder?

Comment: @user2256532 Yes, if you want your `.dll` in another folder, you can change the `Path` environment variable. But you have to do it on every computer you test your program. You can do it with [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about).

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma comment lib` doesn't accept object files, only libraries. I see that you have a c.lib file,  and I assume that is the library file you need to include with pragma directive, so change it to `#pragma comment( lib, "c.lib")`

Comment: I tried c.lib, then I get an error -> c.dll not found even though it is in the same folder as c.lib

Comment: You should check that c.dll is in a path that is configured for executable files (unfortunately I don't have visual studio to give you details). However, this path is different from the input library paths.